# Should there be a tag for questions about Scheme?

Tags: discussion, tags, lilypond

There are over 400 questions with tag [lilypond](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lilypond) on SE: MP&T, these are about the music programming language LilyPond.
However, at least 20 of theses *questions** are really about Scheme.

Scheme is used *by* LilyPond (and *in* some lilypond files explicitly), but it is ~basically~ a different programming language.

**Would it be worthwhile to introduce a new tag for these questions?** (.e.[scheme](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scheme) or similar)
**Or, are there some reasons that this would not a good idea?**

I am assuming that these questions are on-topic, but this is perhaps debatable. I'm thinking that this *is* a valid assumption though, because question on LilyPond [are on-topic](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2363/lilypond-programming-questions-on-so) and LilyPond uses Scheme.

If this tag is created, it should probably *always* be used in conjunction with the LilyPond tag, because questions about Scheme that aren't also about LilyPond aren't going to be on-topic in SE: MP&T, (whereas they would be on-topic on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scheme)).

---

<sub>* Many more answers are scheme based, but I'm specifically talking about questions here.</sub>

Comment: I'd be interested in a new tag, however `scheme` is very generic maybe `scheme-lang` instead? Like I can see someone trying to use scheme as rhyme scheme

Comment: @Dom We've gotten enough questions that a new tag makes sense to me. To the best of my memory, all of them relate to LilyPond, so [tag:lily-scheme]?

Comment: It occurs to me to wonder whether we should have a scheme for questions about tags.

Comment: @Aaron That would be a meta issue.

Comment: I guess we need a meta scheme-tagging scheme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update

Okay, so I am going to take +4 votes as a resounding consensus; it's agreed that a tag should be created for scheme questions.

The new tag will be [lily-scheme](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lily-scheme):

- this is better than the generic [scheme](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scheme) might be,
- and it is explicit that the tag is for LilyPond related Scheme questions.

---

I'll start applying the tag, so prepare yourselves for a drip feed of scheme questions; 2 per day for a couple of weeks should do it.

I've preposed tag info, but as I really don't know much about scheme — it's just a couple of quotes from reputable sources.  Someone who knows scheme can improve on it.